# Default property value in plugin configuration when parent POM not define that property

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

Here is my scenario

I have a POM file which using a custom plugin we have developed lets say mycutom-plugin  and that plugin  use another plugin called asciidoctor-maven-plugin

So I'll note down my concern here 
 
1. I have a parameter(asciidoctor.sectnumlevels) in asciidoctor-maven-plugin as a configuration property please see below xml and this parameter value is passed by parent POM that this plugin being used.

Now what I wanted have a default value set for ${asciidoctor.sectnumlevels} from mycutom-plugin's POM when I don't pass value from parent POM that plugin being used

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${asciidoctor-maven-plugin.version} </version>
                .......
                    <attributes>
                        <toc2>left</toc2>
                ......
            <sectnumlevels>${asciidoctor.sectnumlevels}</sectnumlevels>

                    </attributes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Please see how i defined property in parent POM

```
<properties>        
    <asciidoctor.sectnumlevels>4</asciidoctor.sectnumlevels>        
</properties>
```

Additionally i've tested below solution as well,but this way it's taking default value but when i pass the value from POM as a property plugin end, it's not overriding

```
    <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>asciidoctor.param.default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <property>
                <name>!asciidoctor.sectnumlevels</name> <!--if not defined from parent POM-->
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <asciidoctor.sectnumlevels>3</asciidoctor.sectnumlevels> <!--set default value-->
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure to understand your setup here. It seems to me that you are mentioning 3 pom files : parent, children and mycutom-plugin.

You can not pass default value from mycustom-plugin pom file to your project. You can define default values in your plugin code though.

To pass defaut value from your parent to your children, you don't need to define a profile, simply define the defaut value in parent pom, then override the same value in your children pom if needed.
Both declaration in parent and children are done the same way :

```
<properties>        
     <asciidoctor.sectnumlevels>4</asciidoctor.sectnumlevels>        
</properties>
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Here is the catch!! Yes as you said I can override property value in the child POM from parent POM. please closely look at my requirement which is, When parent POM did not define only I need to reflect child property default value whereas if parent POM defined I need get overridden child property value by parent value !! I think you got my point

Comment: Ho ok. It is a bit strange. It seems to be quite a complicated use case. How can you be in the situation where you define a property in the child pom not knowing what the parent pom contains ?

Comment: Parent POM uses a plugin and plugin have some configuration,  In case of parent POM doesn't pass particular override value so  plugin itself should assign a value to his configuration